# TLS Client не читает все сообщение в буфер

Tags: golang, tls

Есть TLS client через который я читаю данные с сервера. Но когда он принимает информацию то читает только часть. Увеличение буфера не помогает.

```
cert2_b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(conf.Config.TLS_pem)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    priv2_b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(conf.Config.TLS_key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    priv2, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(priv2_b)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    cert := tls.Certificate{
        Certificate: [][]byte{cert2_b},
        PrivateKey:  priv2,
    }

    config := &tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}, InsecureSkipVerify: true}

    //----CREATE_CONNECTION
    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", serv, config)
    if err != nil {
        println("client: ", err.Error())
        log.Println("client: ", err.Error())
        return err
    }

listen := make([]byte,5000)
n, err = co.Conn.Read(listen)
println("n:",n)
```

Для тестирования ставил цикл, тогда он принимает полное сообщение

```
for{
    n, err = co.Conn.Read(listen)
    println("n:",n)
}
```

выводит
n: 1187
listen
n: 966

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно, `Read` не обязан заполнять буфер целиком. Для этого существует [`io.ReadFull`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull). Такой код постарается считать буфер целиком:

```
n, err = io.ReadFull(co.Conn, listen)
```

Comment: а разве o.ReadFull не читает до тех пор пока буфер не будет заполнен? То есть если сообщение будет меньше длинны моего массива байт то тогда он повиснет.

Comment: @Ghost А разве это не то, чего вы хотите? Если нет, то как вы вообще определяете, что сообщение дочитанно?

Comment: Обычно сообщение обрубалось на co.Conn.Read(listen) когда приходило. Если дашь идею лучше то я буду рад.

Comment: предлагаешь всегда передавать сообщение определенной длинны?

Comment: @Ghost Что у вас за сообщение-то? Если JSON, то заверните в `json.Decoder`, и он сделает всё за вас. Если ваш собственный формат пакета, то решайте, как будете передавать длину сообщения. Например, первые 4 байта - длина.

Comment: @Ghost Смотрите документацию своего формата сериализации. Это уже походит на новый вопрос, честно говоря.